# How to get high of a 15 min candle at a particular time on a particular date in pinescript?

Tags: timestamp, pine-script, tradingview-api

I want a single floating value as output which is the high of a 15 min candle at a particular input time and input date in pinescript. And I want it in v4 of pinescript. Can you please help with code using timestamp and hline functions?

I tried looking for code but all i got was series of time closing rather than a particular horizontal line plotted on the graph whose value is high of a 15 min candle. I want it in such a way that even if I change the timeframe it should still calculate for 15 mins.

```
study(title="Bhaskar TGT SL Timer Strategy", shorttitle="Bhaskar_Strat", overlay=true)

lineDate = input(timestamp("1 Dec 2022 10:00:00"), title="Line Location",type=input.time)
var float new = na
if year==year(lineDate) and month==month(lineDate) and dayofmonth==dayofmonth(lineDate) and hour==hour(lineDate) and minute==minute(lineDate)
    new=high
new=security(syminfo.tickerid,"15",year==year(lineDate) and month==month(lineDate) and dayofmonth==dayofmonth(lineDate) and hour==hour(lineDate) and minute==minute(lineDate))
hline(float(new))
```

Could you please check this, although getting the high of 15 min candle is what is needed.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/IUjGOVOO/ Heres the image of how I want it to be. High and low of Dec 1st 10:00am candle

Comment: Can you gave us example so we can help you ?

Comment: alright. May i know how to share code?

Comment: To share code, edit your question and select insert code and paste it

Comment: yes please check the answer below

Comment: Answer is for.... answer. You should edit your question and delete this false answer

Comment: Done, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this :

```
//@version=4
study(title="Bhaskar TGT SL Timer Strategy", shorttitle="Bhaskar_Strat", overlay=true)

lineDate = input(timestamp("1 Dec 2022 10:00:00"), title="Line Location",type=input.time)
// Calcul of the number of bars back to go 
// based on 15 min candle
bars_back = int( (time - lineDate)/1000/60/15 )-1
indexHighTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
indexCurrTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1
high15min = security(syminfo.tickerid,"15", high[indexHighTF])[indexCurrTF]
low15min = security(syminfo.tickerid,"15",low[indexHighTF])[indexCurrTF]

if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index, high15min[bars_back], bar_index -1, high15min[bars_back],extend=extend.both, color=color.lime)
    line.new(bar_index, low15min[bars_back], bar_index -1, low15min[bars_back],extend=extend.both, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code but can I get the value of the high and low as a input float rather than a series float. Or please mention how to convert because using these high and low I calculate Targets 1 to 6.

Comment: @AshishDhage There is no way in pinescript to change a serie float to a float

Comment: oh thats sad. Is there any workaround? Like to write code only to fetch non series float value which is just a single float value at a particular date and time of '15 minute timeframe'

Comment: @AshishDhage The code in my answer is a workaround